# php + javascript string checking

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is failing to pass the below requirement:-

```
$uid = ca11a15e (the value called from database)

function _checkSn($uid)    
{
   $match1 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d][1-6][a-z]\d{2}e$/',$uid);
   $match2 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]school$/',$uid);
   $match3 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]master$/',$uid);
   $match4 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]ee01$/',$uid);
   $doesMatch = ($match1 || $match2 || $match3 || $match4);
   return $doesMatch; 
}
```

Actually, what is the phase talking about? and how shall I modify it so that the $uid can pass the checking?

Comment: should $uid's value be inside quotes? Is that a typo or how your program is?

Comment: the $uid is generated by the system, with the following rule
cal = school
1a = class of the student
15 = class number of the student
e = course enrolled

Comment: How is that related to javascript?

Comment: should `$uid = ca11a15e` be `$uid = 'ca11a15e'` is basically @LeonardChallis question

Comment: Also you can combine your 4 RegEx'es to one like `preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]([1-6][a-z]\d{2}e|school|master|ee01)$/',$uid);`

Comment: Ham, I updated my answer to include the option for c or p at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d][1-6][a-z]\d{2}e$/',$uid) 
|| preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]school$/',$uid) 
|| preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]master$/',$uid) 
|| preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]ee01$/',$uid));
```

uid matches the pattern if it is...

- "p", two times either a lowercase letter or digit, followed by
- one digit 1-6, another letter, two digits, "e" or "school" or "master" or "ee01"

For example, this would match: "p6t3h56e" (first pattern), or "p9hschool" (second).

"ca11a15e" will not match any of these because they all require a "p" at the start.

By the way, this can be shortened to:

```
return (preg_match('/^p[a-z\d]{2}([1-6][a-z]\d{2}e|school|master|ee01)$/',$uid);
```

Are all the uid's going to start with a c? Maybe you meant this, which would match "ca11a15e" (Note the c instead of p):

```
return (preg_match('/^c[a-z\d]{2}([1-6][a-z]\d{2}e|school|master|ee01)$/',$uid);
```

Comment: may I change it to (preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2}([1-6][a-z]\d{2}e|school|master|ee01)$/',$uid) so that the first 2 characters can be any letter? or I shall I change it to (preg_match('/^pc[a-z\d]{2}([1-6][a-z]\d{2}e|school|master|ee01)$/',$uid) so that it can cater both c and p?

Comment: To allow for either p or c, you need to put them in a group like [cp]. Just cp would only match if there were both c and p.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

Your uid does not begin with a 'p'.  All rules are checking that it begins with 'p'.

**Long answer**

```
$match1 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d][1-6][a-z]\d{2}e$/',$uid);
```

This is checking for something of the format:
the letter p, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, number from 1 to 6, lowercase letter, number (1 or 2 digits), the letter e

```
$match2 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]school$/',$uid);
```

This is checking for something of the format:
the letter p, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, the word 'school'

```
$match3 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]master$/',$uid);
```

This is checking for something of the format:
the letter p, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, the word 'master'

```
$match4 = preg_match('/^p[a-z\d][a-z\d]ee01$/',$uid);
```

This is checking for something of the format:
the letter p, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, lowercase letter, 1 digit number, the string 'ee01'

**EDIT**

If you wish to add 'c' to the allowed characters at the start of the matching, you can, for example do:

```
$match1 = preg_match('/^[cp][a-z\d][a-z\d][1-6][a-z]\d{2}e$/',$uid);
```

`[cp]` instead of `p` checks for EITHER c or p as the first letter.